# install yii in subdirectory

Tags: yii, subdirectory

On my hosted server i have several yii websites that use a single yii framework. On this particular one i want to put the yii app in a sub-directory. The only page thats opening is the index, when i go to all other pages like register i get a 404 error page. Must be something with the htaccess file, since its so foreign to me.

directory structure.

i need to be able to put the yii webapp inside the app directory instead of either site1, site2 or site3 directory.

```
/yiiframework
   /site1
   /site2
   /site3/app
```

index file

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';



require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

config main.php url manager settings

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

        ),
    ),
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problems, but I think the root .htaccess could be clashing with your site-.htaccess. Try  to remove (rename) the .htaccess in your /yiiframework and test. Don't forget to restore it when you are done! Also check that assets and runtime-folders are writeable.

Comment: Check basePath value in your config/main.php

Answer (score 0):

Ant scripts- that is what you need bro. In company with hudson (teamcity etc.)  it`s just a magice =)